# What do the Max-Cut algorithm graph cuts mean?

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory, combinatorics

The max-cut algorithm divides a graph into 2 subsets, for instance:

[image]

While I understand the algorithm, I do not quite understand the meaning of the result. In the above picture, what does the groupings of black circles vs white circles mean?

If these lines were internet connections between different locations, what do the subgroups black/white location mean/indicate?

Comment: You got the picture from the wikipedia page at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut . It might be useful to explain which part of the description on that page you don't understand, because otherwise people will simply paraphrase the description you can find there already.

Comment: As for the application: The algorithm may simply not be useful to partitioning the internet. But the wikipedia article has a number of actual applications.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth thank you. I guess I don't understand what the result means. If those represent 5 cities and roads between them, then by applying MaxCut algorithm we have classified these cities into 2 subsets (white and black nodes). But I don't quite understand what do these subsets mean and what is the significance of this classification into 2 subsets?

Comment: It's a subdivision of cities into two sets of approximately equal size so that the number of roads that connect the two sets is maximal. I don't know why you would be interested in making the number of roads maximal, but if you want to go with the cities/roads metaphor, that's what it is.